# Removing Unique_together relationship from class Meta?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I want to remove the `unique_together` constraint from  `class Meta` of the below model .

```
class x(models.Model):
   basket = ...
   line_reference = ...
   ...
   class Meta:
        unique_together = ("basket", "line_reference")
        verbose_name = _('Basket line')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Basket lines')
```

I tried commenting the `unique_together` line and running `makemigrations` but no change is detected by Django. I checked using views this relationship constraint still exists. How can I remove this relationship. My db is `postgresql`.

Comment: One solution is to go into `psql` shell and alter this table by dropping the constraint. Command : `ALTER TABLE basket_line DROP CONSTRAINT "basket_line_basket_id_line_reference_key";`

Comment: "I tried commenting the unique_together line and running makemigrations but no change is detected by Django." -> Either your app doesn't have migrations, or there's an error in Django.

Answer (score 4):

Commenting in models.py will not help here as migrations work if only it sees an alteration in relations and their attributes you create. **unique_together** is a constraint and migrations don't detect them if you just comment.

I am hoping you still have your migrations folder and all generated migrations intact.

**If** anything is messed up too badly **and** you are on your own developer environment which does not disturb anyone else, go ahead and clear all migrations and just reset the db.

**Else** Here is what you can try if you still have migrations and don't want to delete them.
Steps :

- goto migrations file which has `migrations.AlterUniqueTogether` the first time in list of all migration files done, and comment that and all subsequent occurrence.
- login to psql shell and to your database. Use `\d+ <table name>` to see all indexes and constraints. Find the one constraint which has `("basket", "line_reference")`. Drop it. Command would be `ALTER TABLE <table_name> DROP CONSTRAINT <name_of_constraint>`
- Now just run `migrate <app_name>` OR `migrate`

Hope this works.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, in my case I only needed to comment out the previous `migrations.AlterUniqueTogether`s and then the last Django-created `migrations.AlterUniqueTogether` migrated without error.

Comment: I am pretty new to Django and python, but still, commenting unique_together and running `makemigrations` does work. Migrations will detect them. `makemigrations` do detect constraints.